# numba JIT with scipy.interpolate spline object

Tags: scipy, numba, spline

In my python code I deal with cubic splines of data:

```
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline

...

xy_interp = CubicSpline(x.copy(), y.copy(), bc_type='natural')
```

Later on in the code I want to use this interpolation in a function which I want to JIT-compile for use with the scipy ODE solver:

```
def RHS(t, z, xy_i):
    y_new = xy_i(t)

    rhs = np.exp(-t)*y_new

    return rhs
```

the problem is that the numba JIT cannot do a no python compilation of the `RHS` function because it cannot recognize the type of the `xy_i` argument, because it is an interpolation object. What are my options here? Is there a way to bypass this and JIT-compile with `nopython=True`?

Comment: `xy_interp` is a callable class instance.  The best you can do is get `y_new` for a whole array `t`, and use that in your `numba` code.  In other words, you can't use `numba` to accelerate the spline calculation.

Comment: The problem with that is the solver will need to evaluate the spline at arbitrary values of `t` which are not known from the beginning. Moreover, I am not trying to speed up the spline calculation, I am only trying to pass the spline object to a function.

Comment: You cannot use Numba to compute `xy_i(t)` but you could for `np.exp(-t)*y_new` assuming `t` is a float or an integer or an array containing that. However, there is no reason to think Numba will produce a faster code here. In fast, I expect it to be slower on recent Intel machine since Numpy now (since few month) use AVX-512 SIMD instructions to compute the exponential while Numba use by default the libc implementation that tends not to use a fast SIMD implementation (the SVML can be used too but it is not available on all platforms, and at least not by default).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to bypass this and JIT-compile with nopython=True?

You cannot use object types in a `nopython=True` Numba function. Indeed, the [documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html) states:

> The behaviour of the nopython compilation mode is to essentially compile the decorated function so that it will run entirely **without the involvement of the Python interpreter**.

The thing is the Python interpreter is needed to work on object. Even passing object reference requires function calls of the CPython interpreter due to the *reference counting*. In fact, the `nopython` mode is fast because Numba can get ride of (slow) CPython object function calls and also because *it can assign a well-defined type to all variables* (ie. *static typing*).

> What are my options here?

One solution is to reimplement the spline function in Numba. THe alternative solution is to split the function in two parts: one dealing with pure-Python objects and a Numba nopython function that takes the result of the previous one to compute `np.exp(-t)*y_new`. The former solution probably the best one assuming Numba is required. The latter is certainly not efficient because of the overhead of the additional function call and the one of the scipy function.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably hack around the fact that CubcSpline evaluation is using a low-level C routine (see `PPoly. __call__` method). So you can construct the object make your jitted code talk to this low-level routine. This is not trivial and certainly not supported by scipy.